# How do I get data that has been returned from a method and use it in that same method again?

Tags: python

My code:

At the end of getData():

```
return dPrev, tPrev
```

```py
dPrev = 135000
tPrev = 17000000
n = 0
while(flag):
  if n == 0:
    getData(dPrev,tPrev)
    time.sleep(600)
    n += 1
  else:
    dPrev, tPrev = getData(dPrev,tPrev)
    getData(dPrev,tPrev)
    time.sleep(600)
    n += 1
```

My error message:

*File "main.py", line 87, in module 
getData(dPrev,tPrev)*

What's happening here?

Comment: That's not the entire error message.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]  and the entire error message. A description of what you want to accomplish would also be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the loop starts, you simply need to capture the return value of `getData` to reuse on the next iteration.

```
dPrev = 135000
tPrev = 17000000
while(flag):
    dPrev, tPrev = getData(dPrev,tPrev)
    time.sleep(600)
    n += 1
    # need some code to clear flag to allow the loop to terminate
```